# Remmina remote desktop RDP randomly logs off

Tags: rdp, remmina

I am using the Remmina remote desktop connection on Ubuntu 12.04 to create RDP connection. The system on the remote desktop is Windows Server 2003 RC Standard 64 edition which logs off by itself randomly. It terminates the connection, so you have to re-connect.

For example: Terminates when I want  to switch to another application or simply change the desktop. On another PC (which is running on Windows) this problem does not occur.

Does the Remmina have timeout or logoff settings which can cause this problem? 
What could be the solution?

Comment: I had a similar problem - after reading a few bug reports, I turned off the sound setting in the connection details. I haven't had a random disconnect since then. Dylan

Comment: To solve this problem, I reinstalled with the latest Remmina client (with all it's dependencies). See this URL and follow the steps: https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki

Answer (score 0):

There can be a number of issues related to the Windows end of the RDP connection.

Check the system log on the Windows machine around the time of the disconnection and the RDP logs errors there:
Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> System

Here are two good troubleshooting guides from the Microsoft community which may help.

- [How to resolve the issue “Remote Desktop Disconnected” or “Unable to Connect to Remote Desktop (Terminal Server)”](https://web.archive.org/web/20160121051651/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2011/01/10/how-to-resolve-the-issue-remote-desktop-disconnected-or-unable-to-connect-to-remote-desktop-terminal-server.aspx)
- [Troubleshooting RDP Client connection problems](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/remote/terminal-server-client-connection-failures)